# Error trying to validate a form in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, methods

I try to validate a form in rails. I have a model called `Vehicle` and I want to be sure that the `Plate` field is required. This is the code in the model:

```
class Vehicle < ActiveRecord::Base
  mount_uploader :image, PictureUploader
  validates_presence_of :plate
end
```

When I try to register a new `vehicle` i receive the following error:

```
NoMethodError in Vehicles#create
Showing /home/damaroja/webapps/gestaller/gestaller/app/views/vehicles/_form.html.erb where line #28 raised:

undefined method `map' for nil:NilClass
```

The system tells me I don't have a error Method. How is this possible?

This is the _form.html.erb

```
<%= form_for(@vehicle) do |f| %>
   <% if @vehicle.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(@vehicle.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this  vehicle from being saved:</h2>

      <ul>
      <% @vehicle.errors.full_messages.each do |message| %>
        <li><%= message %></li>
      <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :image %><br>
    <%= f.file_field :image %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :plate %><br>
<%= f.text_field :plate %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :places %><br>
    <%= f.number_field :places %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :type %><br>
    <%= f.select 'make', options_for_select(@listadotipos) %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
   <%= f.label :mam %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :mam %>
```

.......

This is the controller code:

```
  def create
    @vehicle = Vehicle.new(vehicle_params)
   @vehicle.save
    respond_with(@vehicle)
  end

  def new
    @vehicle = Vehicle.new
        tipos= Type.all
        @listadotipos=[]
        tipos.each do |h|
          @listadotipos.push(h.name)
        end
    respond_with(@vehicle)
 end
```

Comment: you don't have a create method in your vehiclesController. So when you submit the form, it complains that it can't find the create method.

Comment: Rails can't find the create method????

Comment: Show your controller.

Comment: We need to see the related controller code, possibly the related form. Code should be narrowed down to just enough to recreate the problem.

Comment: Line 28 of your `_form.html.erb` partial is calling `map` on nil. Can you post the content of of your form partial, as well as the `create` method of your controller?

Comment: The problem is almost certainly `<%= f.select 'make', options_for_select(@listadotipos) %>`. Should you be assigning `@listadotipos` in your `create` action?